# HERE SDK Premium Android - Strange behavior with OFFLINE navigation: no ReRouting and getting no RouteGuidance Maneuvers

Tags: android, here-api

Sorry guys, i need your help!
i'm trying to implement an offline navigator using HERE SDK Premium on Android and all is working fine so far.

BUT...
1) When using the navigator on car, moving on a calculated route, i have no maneuver indication nor maneuver speech. Strange fact: if i use SIMULATION on same route, all is working as expected!!!

2) If i deviate from my calculated route, no recalculation happens... i'm pretty sure the offline mode can handle a basic rerouting, but i cannot make it work!

Comment: Your question got marked for moderation since it is your first post.  If this question is about the here-api, add that tag.  The HERE FAQ suggests using that tag as well https://developer.here.com/help has this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/here-api.  You can also search for them with [here-api].  You question could be improved by: including example code that demonstrates the problem, 2) including a summary of the effort you have already put into finding an answer on your own... at least some google search keywords.

Answer (score 0):

i rewrote all my navigation code (2 years old code) from scratch using the examples from HERE line-by-line and now all seems to work as exptected.
Still no idea of what i've done wrong last time.

Can close thread if you like